# How can i crop a frame sequence with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to crop a video frame sequence by frame number. For example for 10000 frames  sequence, i want to crop it 750 frame from beginning.

Comment: Hi @Gyan - if you post an answer, ideally with an example of syntax as well as the link, we can upvote it. Comments are generally temporary so your comment here will go eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg's image sequence demuxer has a start_number option, so if you want to skip img_0749.jpg and start from img_0750.jpg, you would start your command as follows,

```
ffmpeg -start_number 750 -i img_%04d.jpg ...
```

See the docs for the image2 demuxer at http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1